# How long do MtGox withdrawals take?

Tags: mtgox, wire-transfers, withdrawal

On Thursday, August 1st, I withdrew (or so I was given to understand) some dollars from my MtGox account.  They were to be wire-transferred to a checking account in the USA.  When the money hadn't shown up after two weeks, I sent an email to MtGox asking how I could tell where the transaction is in the queue.  I got a reply that didn't answer that question, but said that transactions are taking longer than they would like.  The money still hasn't been transferred.

Is this amount of time typical, or did this somehow get lost?  Is there some way to tell where in the queue I am?

Comment: I'll write this as a comment since it doesn't really answer the question: It is known that Mtgox are currently experiencing severe problems with withdrawals. It could definitely take weeks until you get your money, and I don't know of a way to know your current status.

Comment: I made my withdrawal on July 17th. Still no money in my account.

Comment: I made withdrawals on July 11th and July 13th and still have not seen my money.

Comment: I am waiting for a significant USD withdrawal from June 27. No luck so far and MtGox has no ETA.

Comment: I waited six weeks and MtGox could still not give me an ETA for the withdrawal. So I cancelled the withdrawal, bought Bitcoins, transferred them to a different exchange and sold them. I've moved virtually all of my money out of MtGox that way. It cost me about 10% - but that's better than the 100% that I fear will happen at MtGox.

Comment: @MtGoxAbandoner, how could you cancel a withdrawal request after it is submitted?

Comment: @Pacerier : You might have to contact MtGox by email to do that.  I think they will attend to that on the same day even if it takes months or aeons to withdraw dollars.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, oh and will they charge it?

Comment: @Pacerier : I don't understand your question.  I think if you cancel a withdrawal of $100 they will just credit $100 to your MtGox account.  My account there says I have a certain number of dollars and a certain number of bitcoins.  In early August I attempted to withdraw some dollars, and I'm still waiting for that to happen.  I would presume that if I cancel the withdrawal they would credit to my account the number of dollars I was withdrawing.

Comment: @Pacerier : I would add that although dollar withdrawals may take months, bitcoin withdrawals can be done in minutes.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, oh my your august withdrawal still has not been processed?

Comment: @Pacerier : It still hasn't happened.

Answer (score 2):

I requested a transfer on July 22 and still haven't received it yet. There was a bounty offered for people to prove that they've received a wire in USD from Mt.Gox from the moment in which they announced they had resumed withdrawals. Only one user claimed it and he requested his wire on July 3 (which was July 4 on Japan time which is Mt.Gox's time zone). Unfortunately, it seems he's the only person to have gotten paid so far or the others aren't sharing any info.

Thread here:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=251895.160