# How long for wire transfer from MtGox to Australian Bank?

Tags: mtgox, wire-transfers

Similar to this [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12791/how-long-do-mtgox-withdrawals-take) but I am interested to know how long it has taken people to get paid from a withdrawal to an Australian Bank.  I had a withdrawal on 30/oct/2013, and have not received the funds yet.

Comment: Was there any update on this? How long did it take for you to complete your withdrawal to AUD?

Comment: no money yet... ;-(

Comment: I've been waiting about the same amount of time for a withdrawal to a US banking institution.  I'm not sure if they've turned into a scam or what (previously had no trouble with withdrawals).  Even their "it could take up to X weeks" claims have been exceeded by a huge margin at this point.  At the moment I'd advise looking for a different exchange.

Comment: yes, i agree as well.  makes you think if the whole thing is not some huge ponzi scheme. i have no cash yet, but i have created a support ticket with the mtgox.

Comment: Still waiting. Withdrawal requested on 2013/11/15 and its now 2014/02/03, 11 weeks and counting. Does anyone know any other reliable way to get AUD out?

Answer (score 1):

[mtgox support desk](https://support.mtgox.com/entries/21649594-Withdrawals-and-Deposits): "Situation as of 24-Nov-2013: We are currently processing withdrawals requested 5 weeks ago." so it seems that you may get your money at the middle of december.